# ASP Page_PreInit

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I am using a Page_PreInit method in a page using dynamic controls, has it destroyed the old controls and values before this event fires on PostBack? I am asking because I want to use the method, if possible to store the existing data into a new class object so that the values of the dynamic controls are then loaded in the Page_Init event. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: have you tried this to see what happens.. what have you tried thus far.. can you show some coded example to support your question..?

Comment: yes it destroy on PostBack, you need to store each time

Comment: Yeah i tried it. thanks Sharique for the reply. i am new to ASP so i am trying to find best options to be more efficient and retain data easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"has it destroyed the old controls and values"?

For the instance whose `Page_PreInit` is executing, there is no "old controls and values". It is a new instance that does not "know" what happened with other instances of the same `Page` class.

On the other hand, at the same time, there may be multiple other instances of the same `Page` type going through any stage of their life-cycles - processing requests from other users.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. I was trying to figure that part out. Makes better sense now.